# extracting specific URL based on a condition from a log file in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have this log file and I have to extract REQ-URL (Actually it is 2 lines long)  of only Passed test cases. How do I check first if it is a Passed test case then extract it ?   This list is 10 pages long. Please someone help me with this issue. I am stuck with this issue for a while now.

```
[Case MostPopular-BlogFlag] 
[REQ-URL]: http://hostname:8080/guiderest?
customerId=cisco&code=news&guide=MostPopular&attrFilter=BlogFlag:true&v=1
***Passed!***
  .
  .
  .
[Case MostPopular-BlogFlag] 
[REQ-URL]: http://hostname:8080/guiderest?
customerId=cisco&code=news&guide=MostPopular&attrFilter=BlogFlag:true&v=1
***Failed!***
```

Thank you well in advance.

Comment: Did you test any of these answers you were given?

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement a basic state machine.

```
if ( $line =~ /REQ_URL/) {
    $maybe_line = $line ;
    $append = 1 ;
} elsif ( $line =~ /\*\*\*(Passed|Failed)/ {
      if ( $1 =~ /Passed/ ) {
         output_line($maybe_line,$line) ;
      }
      $append = "" ; 
      $maybe_line = "" ; 
} else {
    if ( $append ) {
       $maybe_line .= $line
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  The main issue here is that I also use the same regex ( $line =~ /REQ_URL/) but it only extracts that line but the URL is continued on the next line as well if you see the code. How do I get that ? I tried using ( $line =~ /REQ_URL/s) , //s where 's' modifier checking for the line break but  then it reads all the following lines. I just want to read the next line.  Please advice.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your code does extract the URL but it only extracts the first line of REq-URL but we have to get the entire url which is also on the next line of [REQ-URL] so how would that work ???

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my $string = '[Case MostPopular-BlogFlag1] 
[REQ-URL]: http://hostname:8080/guiderest?
customerId=cisco&code=news&guide=MostPopular&attrFilter=BlogFlag:true&v=1
***Passed!***
  .
  .
  .
[Case MostPopular-BlogFlag] 
[REQ-URL]: http://hostname:8080/guiderest?
customerId=cisco&code=news&guide=MostPopular&attrFilter=BlogFlag:true&v=1
***Failed!***';

while($string =~ /\[Case\h+(?<case>[^]]+)]\s*\[REQ-URL]:\h+(?<url>\S+(\?\R\S+)?)\s*\*+Passed!\*+/g) {
    print $+ {case} . "\n" . $+ {url} . "\n\n";
}
```

The pattern will fail if `***Passed!***` is not after.

Comment: Thanks very much for the quick reply. I tried running your code, but it does not show any output.

Comment: @user2457969: I have tested it, and it works. See my edited answer with the working example.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to set Perl's record separator (`$/`) to "[Case MostPopular-BlogFlag]", so the log is read in 'chunks' seperated by that string.  Next, use a regex that includes "***Passed!" and if it's not there, get the next record.  If found, remove any newlines from the captured URL, and then print it:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

local $/ = '[Case MostPopular-BlogFlag]';

while (<>) {
    next unless my ($url) = /\[REQ-URL\]:\s+([^*]+)\*\*\*Passed!/;
    $url =~ s/\n//g;
    print "$url\n";
}
```

Usage: `perl script.pl inFile [>outFile]`

The last optional parameter directs output to a file.

Hope this helps!